# Margin Top not working in ie7 if i apply position fixed

Tags: html, css

I am having problem with margin-top in ie7 if i use position fixed in css.

I searched in web for a solution and tried many but nothing worked.

margin-top for the test div is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> test </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/><![endif]-->



</head>

<body>
<div id="fixed1">
<div id="fixed"></div>
</div>


<div id="test">
ayhd iaudiuawdyiaudyw
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,
pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, 
q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, 
form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
border : 0;
outline : 0;
font-weight : inherit;
font-style : inherit;
font-size : 100%;
font-family : inherit;
vertical-align : baseline;}
:focus {
outline : 0;
}
body {
line-height : 1;
color : black;
background : white;
}
ol, ul {
list-style : none;
}
table {
border-collapse : separate;
border-spacing : 0;
}
caption, th, td {
text-align : left;
font-weight : normal;
}


#fixed1 {
position : fixed;
width : 100%;
top : 0;
background-color : red;
}
#fixed {
margin : 0 auto;
height : 20px;
background-color : blue;
width : 980px;
}
#test {
margin : 0 auto;
margin-top : 20px;
margin-bottom : 20px;
height : 2000px;
width : 980px;
background-color : red;
}
```

Here is ie7.css

```
#fixed1{
left:0px;
}

#test{
margin-top:30px;
background-color:grey;
}
```

Thank U,
Kishore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9AVa/1/). I have added your code in fiddle. It works for ie 7 also http://jsfiddle.net/S9AVa/1/

Problem was because of margin specified in 2 ways, margin : 0 auto; and again margin-top and margin-bottom. IE considers the first call.

It should be like

```
#test {
margin : 20px auto 20px auto;
float:left;
 height : 2000px;
width : 1040px;
background-color : red;
}
```

and I have added `left:0;` to `fixed1` class.

Updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/S9AVa/2/

Comment: i am having problem with the test div

Comment: this doesnt work coz float:left makes the test div move to the left but i want it to be centered.

Comment: Else you can add margin-top:20px to body class. check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S9AVa/2/

Comment: It is.. I tested here in IE7 and other browsers as well